# Super.tap {} - what does it do and use cases?

Tags: ruby

I came across this construction in a gem and don't understand the intent. 
I know what tap does alone, but why would someone call super.tap {} instead of just continuing the code normally after the super call.

```
def my_method
 super.tap do |u|
    if @user && @user.new_record?
      @omniauth = u.session[:session]
      u.session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`super.tap` is nothing but `tap` method called on whatever `super` returns. User dmnd already explained pretty well what `tap` does (why the downwote?). `super` calls the method from the ancestor class which you are overriding.

So, the code you pasted is equivalent with the following:

```
original_result = super
if @user && @user.new_record?
  @omniauth = original_result.session[:session]
  original_result.session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
end
return original_result
```

Essentially, `super.tap` can be used for wrapping the method from the inherited class, adding some functionality, but keeping the result.

Comment: Your last sentence explains exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 30):

`tap` is used to perform some operations on an object, and then return that object. That sounds confusing, but it's helpful when chaining methods. Example:

```
def make_a_something
  t = Something.new
  t.method
  t.attr = 'foo'
  t # must remember to manually return t, otherwise 'foo' is returned
end
```

can be replaced with

```
def make_a_something
  Something.new.tap do |t|
    t.method
    t.attr = 'foo'
  end
end
```

If that doesn't strike you as terribly useful, [see some further examples here](http://moonbase.rydia.net/mental/blog/programming/eavesdropping-on-expressions).

Comment: In that case maybe your question needs some of the surrounding code for context. super calls the method that is overridden by the current method. What class and method is your code from, and what class does it inherit from?